# How to call macro in a post hook from model files

Tags: dbt

So I have defined a macro under marcos/mymacro.sql. Let say mymacro(param1, param2).

I want to call that macro with parameters in one of my model/mymodel.sql file using a post hook.

```
{{ config(
    materialized = 'table'
) }}
 
WITH source_data AS (
 
    SELECT
        pname
    FROM
        {{ref('example')}}
)
 
SELECT
    *
FROM
    source_data
```

Where should I define the post hook and call that macro with parameters?

Comment: have you checked the docs? https://docs.getdbt.com/reference/resource-configs/pre-hook-post-hook